# Adding data to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having an issue populating my array.  I have a csv file which has 1 column containing some ids.  I load and process the csv and end up with an array like so

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "ID123"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "ID234"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "ID345"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "ID456"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "ID567"
  ]
]
```

Using these ids I hit an API on an id to get data specific to that id.  So I loop the array containing the ids and do something like the following

```
$jobData = array();

foreach($csv as $data) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.somdomain/some.api/get/".$data[0].");
    //other curl stuff

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $output = new \SimpleXMLElement($output);
}
```

Now if I output the result of output, I get something like this

```
SimpleXMLElement {#352 ▼
  +"Job": SimpleXMLElement {#383 ▼
    +"ID": "ID123"
    +"Client": SimpleXMLElement {#387 ▼
      +"ID": "12345"
    }
    +"Assigned": SimpleXMLElement {#392 ▼
      +"Staff": array:5 [▼
        0 => SimpleXMLElement {#403 ▼
          +"ID": "12345"
        }
        1 => SimpleXMLElement {#404 ▼
          +"ID": "23456"
        }
        2 => SimpleXMLElement {#405 ▼
          +"ID": "34567"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So I need to build up an array containing the data for all the IDs that I have.  So within the foreach loop above I am doing something like this

```
foreach($csv as $data) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.somdomain/some.api/get/".$data[0].");
    //other curl stuff

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $output = new \SimpleXMLElement($output);

    if (!empty($output)) {
        $jData['jobInfo'] = array(
            'clientId' => (string)$output->Job->Client->ID,
            'startDate' => '20160701',
            'dueDate' => '20160731'
        );

        if(!empty($output->Job->Assigned->Staff)) {
            foreach ($output->Job->Assigned->Staff as $staff) {
                $jData['staffInfo'][] = array(
                    'staffId' => (string)$staff->ID
                );
            }
        }
    }
    $jobData[] = $jData;
}
```

Now this works to a point.  I added an extra [] onyo the staffInfo element because there can be more than 1 staff member as the output above demonstrates.  The problem I am having with the
above is that it seems to duplicate some things.  So the output of jobData array is as follows

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "jobInfo" => array:4 [▶]
    "staffInfo" => array:5 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "jobInfo" => array:4 [▶]
    "staffInfo" => array:6 [▶]
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "jobInfo" => array:4 [▶]
    "staffInfo" => array:7 [▶]
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "jobInfo" => array:4 [▶]
    "staffInfo" => array:8 [▶]
  ]
  4 => array:4 [▼
    "jobInfo" => array:4 [▶]
    "staffInfo" => array:15 [▶]
  ]
]
```

As you can see, element 0 has an array of size 5 for staffInfo.  Element 1 increases to 6, element 2 is 7, element 3 is 8 and element 4 is 15.  If I manually check the system the API is calling, 
element 0 should have 5 which is correct.  Element 1 should have 1, element 2 should have 1, element 3 should have 1 and element 4 should have 7.

So how do I stop this from adding the previous loops result onto the next result?

Thanks

Comment: This line: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.somdomain/some.api/get/".$data[0].");` is a syntax error. You've missed the closing quotes.

Comment: Sorry was removing code to cut down on what was posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialize `$jData` anywhere. This is a bad practice. As a result, it is always the same. You keep overriding the `jobInfo`, and keep adding to `staffInfo`.

You need to initialize the array at the beginning of every iteration.

Comment: Hi, I have initialised it now but same result

Comment: My mistake, was initialising it in the wrong place.  Manay thanks